# Can't write tabular content in an excel file using pandas ExcelWriter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've created a python script to grab some tabular content from a webpage and write the same in an excel file using pandas `ExcelWriter`. The tabular data are rightly coming through but I'm unable to write them in an excel file. I can write the same using `openpyxl` but in case of pandas `ExcelWriter`, I get stuck.

I've tried with:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas import ExcelWriter

link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Intel_processors"
result = []

res = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for items in soup.select_one("table.wikitable").select("tr"):
    data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.select("th,td")]
    print(data)
    result+=data

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
writer = ExcelWriter('tabular_content.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
writer.save()
```

To avoid any confusion as to what I'm getting and what I wish to get, I've given two examples to depict the picture.

My current approach can write the data in a single column like the following.

```
Processor
SeriesNomenclature
CodeName
Production Date
Supported Features (Instruction Set)
Clock Rate
Socket
Fabri-cation
```

However, I wish to write them like the following:

```
Processor   SeriesNomenclature  CodeName    Production Date Supported Features (Instruction Set)
4004            Nov. 15,1971    
8008    N/A N/A April 1972  N/A
8080    N/A N/A April 1974  N/A
8085    N/A N/A March 1976  N/A
8086    N/A N/A June 8, 1978    N/A
8088    N/A N/A June 1979   N/A
80286   N/A N/A Feb. 1982   N/A
i80386  DX, SX, SL  N/A 1985 - 1990 N/A
i80486  DX, SX, DX2, DX4, SL    N/A 1989 - 1992 N/A
```

P.S. Using `ExcelWriter` is a must.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be a problem with `ExcelWriter` and in this case you don't even need BeautifulSoup. Simply read the data this way

```
    tables = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Intel_processors")

    writer = ExcelWriter('tabular_content.xlsx')
    tables[0].to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
    writer.save()
```

And, at least on my system, it created the Excel file as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jack Fleeting. I'm familiar with `pd.read_html()` but I do not wish to go that way and that is the reason I used BeautifulSoup.